# why this on hover animation is not working properly?

Tags: css, css-transitions

we have this h1 here

```
<h1 class="in">hello</h1>
```

and css for this is

```
    .in{
-webkit-animation:mymove1 3s 1;
   }
.in:hover {
 -webkit-animation:nextT 3s 1;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes "mymove1"
{
0% {opacity:0;
      margin-left:0px;}
100% {opacity:1;
    margin-left: 8px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes "nextT"
{
0% {
     -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    }
100% {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    }
}
```

so onload animation work properly and when i hover it grows up that's what i want but when i remove my mouse from the h1 the "mymove1" animation start again. i cloud not understand why this is happening help me out.you can also check the code working on
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsBtU/)

Answer (score 0):

Heres the code if you want it to change opacity on pageload & resize when you hover without the 'mymove1' animation restarting.

```
    <style>
    .in{
animation:mymove1 3s 1;
transform:scale(1);

/*If You want the hover to ease in and out*/
transition:transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
   }
.in:hover {
transform:scale(1.2);

}
@keyframes mymove1
{
0% {opacity:0;
      margin-left:0px;}
100% {opacity:1;
    margin-left: 8px;}
}

</style>
```